# state & props not refreshing things correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on an accordion configurator.
I'm new to react.

I have three classes:

- Touche who manages 4 select (note pull, note push, octavePull, octavePush)
- Keyboard who displays all the Touche
- KeyboardManager who displays current keyboard plus a selector (for different keyboard setup)

KeyboardManager got a finalKeyboard element which I can edit when I select other notes in the Touche element.

But when I select another configuration keyboard via the selector in keyboard manager. Keyboard child doesn't get the good value and doesn't refresh with the good keyboard.

I don't understand clearly why this is happening.

```
class Touche extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   
    this.state = {
      ligne: props.ligne,
      colonne: props.colonne,
      handleChange: props.onChange,
      dataTouche : props.dataTouche,
    };
  }

  handleChangeNotePull(event) {
     this.state.handleChange('note','pull', event, this.state)
  }
  handleChangeNotePush(event) {
    this.state.handleChange('note', 'push', event, this.state)
  }
  handleChangeOctavePull(event) {
    this.state.handleChange('octave', 'pull', event, this.state)
  }
  handleChangeOctavePush(event) {
    this.state.handleChange('octave', 'push', event, this.state)
  }

  render() {
    return <td>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <Select options={options} value={options[this.state.dataTouche.pull]} onChange={this.handleChangeNotePull.bind(this)} />
              <Select options={options} value={options[this.state.dataTouche.push]} onChange={this.handleChangeNotePush.bind(this)} />
            </td>
            <td>
              <Select options={optionOctave} value={optionOctave[this.state.dataTouche.octpull]} onChange={this.handleChangeOctavePull.bind(this)} />
              <Select options={optionOctave} value={optionOctave[this.state.dataTouche.octpush]} onChange={this.handleChangeOctavePush.bind(this)} />
            </td>
          </tr>

       </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>; 
  }
}
```

Here is my Keyboard class:

```
class Keyboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('constructor keyboard')
    this.state = {
      handleChangeTouche: props.onChange,
    }
  }
  handleChange = (type, pushpull, event, buttonState) => {
    this.state.handleChangeTouche(type, pushpull ,event, buttonState)
  }
  render() {    
    return (    
      this.props.keyboard.map((row, index) =>
        <tr key={index}>
          <Touche dataTouche={row[0]} onChange={this.handleChange} ligne={index} colonne={0}></Touche>
          <Touche dataTouche={row[1]} onChange={this.handleChange} ligne={index} colonne={1}></Touche>
          <Touche dataTouche={row[2]} onChange={this.handleChange} ligne={index} colonne={2}></Touche>
        </tr>
      )
    )
  }
}
```

And my keyboardManager class

```
class KeyboardManager extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedKeyboard: 1,
      finalKeyboard : instrumentKeyboardData[1].keyboard,
    }; 
  }

  handleChangeKeyboard(event) {
    this.setState({
      selectedKeyboard: event.value
    })
    var tempKeyboard =  instrumentKeyboardData[event.value].keyboard
    this.setState({
      finalKeyboard : tempKeyboard
    })
  }

  handleChangeTouche(type, pushpull, e, buttonState) {
    if(type === 'note'){
      var tempKeyboard = this.state.finalKeyboard
      tempKeyboard[buttonState.ligne][buttonState.colonne][pushpull] = e.value
      this.setState({
        finalKeyboard : tempKeyboard
      })
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          options={instrumentKeyboardData}
          value={instrumentKeyboardData[this.state.selectedKeyboard]}
          onChange={this.handleChangeKeyboard.bind(this)}
        />
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <Keyboard keyboard={this.state.finalKeyboard} onChange={this.handleChangeTouche.bind(this)}/>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My accordion data:

```
const instrumentKeyboardData = [
  {
    value: 0, 
    label: 'Concertina',
    keyboard : [
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
    ],
  },
  {
    value: 1,
    label: 'Chroma',
    keyboard: [
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
    ],
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    label: 'Diato',
    keyboard: [
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
    ],
  },
  
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assume that instrumentKeyboardData is a JSON like object not an array and that in it you have a key that has the same value as your event.value.

If it is an array, so you have to use findIndex or filter on it to get the right object.
Let assume the key in the JSON object of keyboard is keyboard_. Then you should do

```
var tempKeyboard =  instrumentKeyboardData[instrumentKeyboardData.findIndex( item => item.keyboard_ === event.value)].keyboard
```

and then

```
handleChangeKeyboard(event) {
    this.setState({
      selectedKeyboard: event.target.value
    })
    var tempKeyboard =  instrumentKeyboardData[instrumentKeyboardData.findIndex( item => item.value === event.value)].keyboard
    this.setState({
      finalKeyboard : tempKeyboard
    })
  }
```

My accordion data :

```
const instrumentKeyboardData = [
  {
    value: 0, 
    label: 'Concertina',
    keyboard : [
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 4, pull: 4 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
    ],
  },
  {
    value: 1,
    label: 'Chroma',
    keyboard: [
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 5, pull: 5 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
    ],
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    label: 'Diato',
    keyboard: [
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
      [{ push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}, { push: 6, pull: 6 , octpull : 1, octpush : 1}],
    ],
  },
  
];
```

Comment: event => {value: 0, label: 'Concertina', keyboard: Array(12)}

Comment: look ok, maybe i missed something but event.value is ok and event.keyboard should too. even with that i can't update keyboard..

Comment: Already updated

Comment: What does this mean ?

Comment: You have to first check if instrumentKeyboardData is an array or a JSON like object

Comment: Ok, so that's look like its a copying issue of an array in the setState